# What does "error code MySql- 1052 Column 'x' in field list is ambiguous" mean?

Tags: sql-delete

I tried to delete from a table, and I got the following error: Error Code: 1052. Column 'clientID' in field list is ambiguous.

```
CREATE DATABASE dogsLife; use dogsLife;

CREATE TABLE Items ( ItemID int PRIMARY KEY, ItemDesc varchar(35), stock int, cost double);

CREATE TABLE Clients ( clientID int PRIMARY KEY, clientName varchar(35), Street varchar(35));

CREATE TABLE Orders ( OrdID int PRIMARY KEY, clientID int, OrderDate date, FOREIGN KEY (clientID) references Clients(clientID) );

CREATE TABLE Items_in_orders ( OrdID int, ItemID int, quantity int, FOREIGN KEY (OrdID) references Orders(OrdID), FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) references Items(ItemID), PRIMARY KEY (OrdID,ItemID) );

DELETE FROM Orders WHERE clientID IN (SELECT clientID FROM Clients INNER JOIN Orders ON Clients.clientID=Orders.clientID INNER JOIN Items_in_orders ON Orders.OrdID=Items_in_orders.OrdID INNER JOIN Items ON Items.ItemID=Items_in_orders.ItemID WHERE (quantity*cost)<100 AND street='Hess');

DELETE FROM Clients WHERE clientID IN (SELECT clientID FROM Clients INNER JOIN Orders ON Clients.clientID=Orders.clientID INNER JOIN Items_in_orders ON Orders.OrdID=Items_in_orders.OrdID INNER JOIN Items ON Items.ItemID=Items_in_orders.ItemID WHERE (quantity*cost)<100 AND street='Hess');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Clients.clientId** instead of just **clientID** in the WHERE clause. Otherwise , the MySQL engine doesn't know if you're trying to reference the primary key on the first table or the foreign key of another table inside the join

Comment: its still doent work.. same error..

DELETE FROM Orders
WHERE Clients.clientID IN (SELECT clientID
       FROM Clients INNER JOIN Orders ON Clients.clientID=Orders.clientID 
          INNER JOIN Items_in_orders ON Orders.OrdID=Items_in_orders.OrdID
                   INNER JOIN Items ON Items.ItemID=Items_in_orders.ItemID
       WHERE (Iquantity*cost)<100 AND street='Hess');

Comment: In that particular DELETE transaction you need to use Orders.clientID, not Clients.clientID . It depends on the alias of the table you want to delete the records from.